# How to lock video size during WebRTC call?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webrtc

I am working on [this](https://github.com/Basscord/webrtc-video-broadcast) video broadcasting example.

I have experienced something I dont know how to fix. During the video call / broadcast the video size seems to be changed by Chrome over time quite often. How can I make the video size / resolution constant?

I dont know if this has an effect, but I commented out the video css styling in the css file (/public/main.css). I commented out this:

> video { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; display: block;
>   top: 0; left: 0; object-fit: cover;}

Can I lock the size with CSS? Or is this a WebRTC thing that I have no influence?

I know that WebRTC can reduce the resolution if for example there is not enough bandwith. But how then to tell WebRTC not to resize video anyway? Is this just a CSS trick after all (haven’t tried it yet)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size at which the video element is displayed using CSS.
Note that you can (for good reasons, typically bandwidth or CPU limitations) not stop WebRTC implementations from reducing the resolution actually sent.

Check either the video elements videoWidth and videoHeight attributes or use the RTCPeerConnection.getStats() API to get the actual resolution.

Comment: I solved the problem myself so far by hiding the video and drawing video's content in a fixed-size canvas at 30fps. I think this cannot be the final solution, because instead of having a video that I hide I will directly draw the WebRTC stream into the fixed size canvas at 30fps.

I did the tests again and while the original (not hidden) video shrinks down after a while (when exposing the camera to a lot of lighting and fast angle changing), the canvas remains at constant size.

PS. when I tried to fix the video's size via css, it did not work...same behavior. Only canvas fixed it.